# Junit - Mocking static method

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, testcase, powermockito

I'm writting a Junit test class "**ServiceImplTest.java**" for following method but its getting null, while trying Marshall xmlRequest.
Can anybody help me out to resolve this issue please. Thanks in advance.

**ServiceImplTest.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({RequestXmlBuilder.class})
public class ServiceImplTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(RequestXmlBuilder.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception {
       PowerMockito.when(RequestXmlBuilder.serviceMarshall(Request, jaxb2Marshaller)).thenReturn("XmlTest");
    }
}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
public class ServiceImpl {
    public Response execute() {
        String xmlRqst = RequestXmlBuilder.serviceMarshall(request, jaxb2Marshaller);
    }
}
```

**RequestXmlBuilder.java**

```
public class RequestXmlBuilder {
    public static String serviceMarshall(Request request, Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller)
            throws JAXBException {
        StringWriter requestXml = new StringWriter();
        jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(request, new StreamResult(requestXml));
        return requestXml.toString();
    }
}
```

Note: Getting null value in below statement

```
jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(request, new StreamResult(requestXml));
```

Comment: Could be a problem in your matchers: `PowerMockito.when(RequestXmlBuilder.serviceMarshall(any(Request.class), any(Jaxb2Marshaller.class))).thenReturn("XmlTest");` Note the `import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;` Could you try it?

Comment: Its woking fine. Thanks you so much @troig

Comment: Your welcome, I've posted it as an answer. Glad to help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @troig . It helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have defined your [matchers](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html) correctly. Could you change it by:

```
PowerMockito.when(RequestXmlBuilder.serviceMarshall(any(Request.class), any(Jaxb2Marshaller.class))).thenReturn("XmlTest");
```

Import for Mockito any matcher, as follows:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
```

Cheers